# Setting R corrplot window background to black

Tags: r, r-corrplot

With the below code I can generate a nice correlation plot.

```
library(corrplot)
df <- data.frame(A=1:10,B=rnorm(10)*(1:10),C=1:10,D=runif(10)*1:10)
df
corrplot(cor(df))
```

Adding the parameter of `bg="black"` will change the colour inside the graph to black.

```
df <- data.frame(A=1:10,B=rnorm(10)*(1:10),C=1:10,D=runif(10)*1:10)
df
corrplot(cor(df),bg="black")
```

Now If I would like to set the whole graph window to black this should work:

```
par(bg="black")
df <- data.frame(A=1:10,B=rnorm(10)*(1:10),C=1:10,D=runif(10)*1:10)
df
corrplot(cor(df),bg="black")
```

But it does not. How to get the whole plotting window to black?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a 2-step way:

```
# First, we need to plot once, to get the extremes of 
# the user coordinates of the plotting region, as set
# by the corrplot function
corrplot(cor(df))

# The extremes are stored
usr <- par("usr")

# New empty plotting window
plot.new()

# Set the new extremes
par(usr=usr)

# Plot a rectangle filled in black, covering the whole plotting window
rect(par("usr")[1],par("usr")[3],par("usr")[2],par("usr")[4],col = "black")

# Finally, plot the corrplot
corrplot(cor(df), bg="black", add = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi Pascal, thanks, works if we change the code for the last line to: corrplot(cor(df), bg="black",add = TRUE) , then all is black.

Comment: And the first line does not seem to be required. Do you agree?

Comment: I don't. Try without the first line.

Comment: Ok, got it. If I use a different data set I get indeed strange output.

Comment: But I agree it is not an ideal solution.